# push down content when hidden div become to be visible?

Tags: javascript, html, position

Got this code, and I got a hidden divs which are unhidden when user click on one of radio buttons. What I would like to achieve is that when hide div will become visible, than button will be push down by this div depends of course of dive height ? what is the best way to get this done ?

```
<head>     
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        function displayForm(c){ 
            if(c.value == "1"){ 
                document.getElementById("form1").style.visibility='visible'; 
                document.getElementById("form2").style.visibility='hidden'; 
            } 
            else if(c.value =="2"){ 
                document.getElementById("form1").style.visibility='hidden'; 
                document.getElementById("form2").style.visibility='visible'; 
            }                            
        }         
    </script>     
<style type="text/css">
#divOne{
    position:absolute;  
    width:70px;
    height:150px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
</style>
</head> 
<body> 
    <form> 
        <label>Form 1<input value="1" type="radio" name="formselector"     onclick="displayForm(this)" /></label>     
        <label>Form 2<input value="2" type="radio" name="formselector" onclick="displayForm(this)" /></label>     
    </form> 

    <div style="visibility:hidden" id="form1"> 
        <div id="divOne"> Message 1 </div>
    </div>
    <div style="visibility:hidden" id="form2"> 
        <div id="divOne"> Message 2 </div>
    </div>  

    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="ClickMe"/>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Do you need to have `position: absolute`? If you get rid of that statement everything will work.

Comment: well without position: absolute; div which hole the button is going down straight away, and other hidden divs shows as well one under the other one, but that's not what I want I want them to be always in the same place on a page no matter which one of them get selected to be visible and I want a button to go down when the div is visible  .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/WU9ZJ/2/
You need to use display : none; and display : block;
Remove the position:absolute; from #divOne

This should be you function:

```
function displayForm(cElem)
{ 
     if(cElem.value == "1"){ 
         document.getElementById("form1").style.display = 'block'; 
         document.getElementById("form2").style.display = 'none'; 
     } 
     else if(cElem.value =="2"){ 
         document.getElementById("form1").style.display = 'none'; 
         document.getElementById("form2").style.display = 'block'; 
     }                            
 }
```

This should be your HTML:

```
<div style="display:none;clear:both;" id="form1"> 
        <div id="divOne"> Message 1 </div>
    </div>
    <div style="display:none;clear:both;" id="form2"> 
        <div id="divOne"> Message 2 </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the css [display] property instead of [visibility].

```
display : none;
```